# How could I write select statement to these two columns?

Tags: sql

Can you write a SQL command for helping me in these two columns?

for example.....these two columns

```
a1             a2
______       ______
1              1
2              1
1              2
2              3
3              1
3              2
4              1
4              2
```

I want the output:

```
a1 a1
1  2
2  3
3  2
4  2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing, based on your example, that you want the second column to be the maximum a2 value for the corresponding a1 value.

Then you want:

```
SELECT a1, MAX(a2) AS a2 FROM table GROUP BY a1
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic aggregates:

```
SELECT a1, MAX(a2) AS a2
  FROM AnonymousTable
 GROUP BY a1;
```